# Aligning a multidimensional array in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, alignment

Is there a way to align the columns of a multidimensional array to make all the values of a column line up properly. For example this is what happens when I System.out my code.

```
    Mon Tue Wed Thurs Fri Sat Sun Average
1   5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5
2   5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5
3   5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5
4   5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5
```

Towards the end because of Thurs text it starts of off set my columns. Is there a way I can line them up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `System.out.printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely checkout http://trac.inamik.com/trac/jtable_format, which is a open-source library for formatting fixed width character based tables.

Comment: You can checkout an example here http://trac.inamik.com/trac/jtable_format/wiki/Example%3AJava

Comment: The iNamik Java Text Table Formatter project has been moved to GitHub: https://github.com/iNamik/Java-Text-Table-Formatter